# How to solve: QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread

Tags: c++, qt, ros, qpixmap

I'm trying to display a sequence of images coming at 30 image per second in `qt label` but I'm getting that error of GUI thread. I did little bit research and I read that it is recommended using `QImage` instead but I'm not sure how to do it in my case.
Here's a shot of my classes and the method I'm using to get the frames:

***main_window.hpp***

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(int argc, char** argv, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public Q_SLOTS:
    void callBackColor(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg);

private:
    Ui::MainWindowDesign ui;
    ros::Subscriber sub;
};
```

***main_window.cpp***

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(int argc, char** argv, QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    ros::init(argc,argv,"MainWindow");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    sub = n.subscribe("/usb_cam/image_raw", 1, &MainWindow::callBackColor, this);
}

void MainWindow::callBackColor(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{

  cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;

  try
  {
    cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
  }

  catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
    return;
  }
  //Here I got the image and I want to display it in a label
  QImage temp(&(msg->data[0]), msg->width, msg->height, 
  QImage::Format_RGB888);
  static QLabel *imageLabel = new QLabel;
  QPixmap pix = QPixmap::fromImage(temp);
  ui.imageLabel->setPixmap(pix);
}
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: "It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread ... Do you have any idea how to solve this?" - 
 Stick to using them in the main/gui thread.. would be the obvious answer..

Comment: @JesperJuhl because that's my question, I don't know how to go that

Comment: Just use QImage between threads and you can at last convert to QPixmap on UI thread. But you don't even have to: no problem to render QImage on any label with overloading of paint event using QPainter.

Comment: Why do you even use `cv_bridge`? `msg` already has the image data that you can wrap in a `QImage`.

Comment: @KubaOber What I shared is just a part of my code that is necessary to understand my issue. I need `opencv` later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback is invoked from an arbitrary thread. Thus the other method calls must be made thread-safe. A simple way to do it is to emit a signal with the image. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40382820/1329652) for other approaches.

But you're also copying the image data unnecessarily. The callback has full control over image lifetime - the `sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr` is a shared pointer, after all. Thus - pass the `ImageConstPtr` all the way to the target thread, then the `QImage` becomes a thin wrapper over the `Image` class, and doesn't copy its data unless a BGR-TO-RGB format conversion is necessary.

There's no need for `cvBridge` at all -- you're not using OpenCV, after all.

Let's start with a minimal reimplementation of ROS that will allow us to try things out on a desktop platform without installing ROS :)

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/qimage-ros-50262348
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Minimal reimplementation of ROS

#define ROS_ERROR qFatal
namespace sensor_msgs {
namespace image_encodings {
const std::string MONO8{"mono8"}, BGR8{"bgr8"}, BGRA8{"bgra8"}, RGB8{"rgb8"}, RGBA8{"rgba8"};
} // image_encodings
struct Image {
   std::vector<quint8> data;
   std::string encoding;
   uint32_t height;
   uint32_t width;
};
using ImagePtr = std::shared_ptr<Image>;
using ImageConstPtr = std::shared_ptr<const Image>;
} // sensor_msgs

namespace ros {
struct Subscriber {};
struct NodeHandle {
   template<class M, class T>
   Subscriber subscribe(const std::string &, uint32_t, void(T::*fun)(M), T *obj) {
      struct Thread : QThread {
         Thread(QObject*p):QThread(p){} ~Thread() override { quit(); wait(); } };
      static QPointer<Thread> thread = new Thread(qApp);
      thread->start(); // no-op if already started
      auto *timer = new QTimer;
      timer->start(1000/60);
      timer->moveToThread(thread);
      QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [obj, fun]{
         auto const msec = QTime::currentTime().msecsSinceStartOfDay();
         QImage img{256, 256, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied};
         img.fill(Qt::white);
         QPainter p{&img};
         constexpr int period = 3000;
         p.scale(img.width()/2.0, img.height()/2.0);
         p.translate(1.0, 1.0);
         p.rotate((msec % period) * 360.0/period);
         p.setPen({Qt::darkBlue, 0.1});
         p.drawLine(QLineF{{-1., 0.}, {1., 0.}});
         p.end();
         img = std::move(img).convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped();
         sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr ptr{new sensor_msgs::Image{
               {img.constBits(), img.constBits() + img.sizeInBytes()},
               sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8,
                     (uint32_t)img.height(), (uint32_t)img.width()}};
         (*obj.*fun)(ptr);
      });
      return {};
   }
};
void init(int &, char **, const std::string &) {}
} // ros
```

The callbacks are invoked from a worker thread, as would happen in ROS.

For demonstration purposes, we can make the main window a `QLabel`. We need to pass the `ImageConstPtr` to the main thread, where it will be wrapped in a `QImage` and set on the label. The signal itself can be the callback. Thus:

```
// Interface

class MainWindow : public QLabel {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   MainWindow(int argc, char** argv, QWidget *parent = {});
protected:
   Q_SLOT void setImageMsg(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr&);
   Q_SIGNAL void newImageMsg(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr&);
private:
   ros::Subscriber sub;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr)
```

First, we need a way to wrap the `ImageConstPtr` in a `QImage`. The `QImage` does not copy the data from the `msg` unless a format conversion is necessary. The image must be consumed while the `msg` is kept alive. The `std::move(image).conversion()` is an idiom for modifying the image in-place. Modern Qt supports this optimization.

```
// Implementation

static QImage toImageShare(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr &msg) {
   using namespace sensor_msgs::image_encodings;
   QImage::Format format = {};
   if (msg->encoding == RGB8 || msg->encoding == BGR8)
      format = QImage::Format_RGB888;
   else if (msg->encoding == RGBA8 || msg->encoding == BGRA8)
      format = QImage::Format_RGBA8888_Premultiplied;
   else if (msg->encoding == MONO8)
      format = QImage::Format_Grayscale8;
   else
      return {};
   QImage img(msg->data.data(), msg->width, msg->height, format);
   if (msg->encoding == BGR8 || msg->encoding == BGRA8)
      img = std::move(img).rgbSwapped();
   return img;
}
```

The implementation of the `MainWindow` and the rest of the demo harness is then quite straightforward:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(int argc, char** argv, QWidget *parent) : QLabel(parent) {
   qRegisterMetaType<sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr>();
#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,0,0)
   connect(this, &MainWindow::newImageMsg, this, &MainWindow::setImageMsg);
#else
   connect(this, SIGNAL(newImageMsg(sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr)), SLOT(setImageMsg(sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr)));
#endif
   ros::init(argc,argv,"MainWindow");
   ros::NodeHandle n;
   sub = n.subscribe("/usb_cam/image_raw", 1, &MainWindow::newImageMsg, this);
}

void MainWindow::setImageMsg(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr &msg) {
   auto img = toImageShare(msg);
   auto pix = QPixmap::fromImage(std::move(img));
   setPixmap(pix);
   resize(pix.size());
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   MainWindow w{argc, argv};
   w.show();
   return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

This concludes the example.

Comment: Wonderful answer. I know you spent time on it so thank you!

Comment: @Ja_cpp Ingen orsak :)